# Potentiometer usage for a 24V 4A pump application

Tags: potentiometer

I have a 24V-4A oil pump that I use for smoke oil in my jet. I currently control the flow by using a needle valve in the oil line which restricts the flow from 2.1 gpm down to .75 gpm.

I am wondering if just reducing the pump speed with a potentiometer is better and easier on the pump, but in one of your articles it appears this will just cause a loss of power and possible heat issue. I was looking at a 100 W potentiometer for this application, but I have an extremely low understanding of if this is smart, and if so... how to connect it for the best results.

Comment: I'm unsure if you are talking about a remote control model jet, or an actual jet. In either case, I would assume weight and efficiency are important. You will likely want to research motor speed control using pulse width modulation (PWM) rather than a bulky rheostat or potentiometer.

Comment: No, potentiometers cannot reliably control a motor. A [servo needle valve](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=servo+valve&_sacat=0&_sop=15) may be useful.